# When click on drop me open dropdown at time one

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

When I click on drop me text so open both dropdown? at time only closest dropdown open. when use closest function but not work that dropdown. this dropdown use multiple time in one page. when use different id so work perfectly work but want to use only class.

```
jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yo9p3jaz/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```js
$(function(){                                  
    var actionopen = $('.allpost-action');
    var actionclose = $('');
    actionopen.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.action-dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
    });
    actionclose.on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.action-dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');

    });
    });
```